# Failed to instantiate module MyApp

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am loading Angularjs dynamically using RequireJS, and although the app initially loads, it produces this [error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3a%20%5B%24injector%3anomod%5D%20http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.4/%24injector/nomod?p0=MyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20%28%3Canonymous%3E%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http://127.0.0.1:7000/js/angular/angular.min.js:6:449%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http://127.0.0.1:7000/js/angular/angular.min.js:20:152%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http://127.0.0.1:7000/js/angular/angular.min.js:21:158%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http://127.0.0.1:7000/js/angular/angular.min.js:28:487%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20%28native%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20%28http://127.0.0.1:7000/js/angular/angular.min.js:7:255%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20%28http://127.0.0.1:7000/js/angular/angular.min.js:28:427%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Yb%20%28http://127.0.0.1:7000/js/angular/angular.min.js:32:462%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Xb.c%20%28http://127.0.0.1:7000/js/angular/angular.min.js:17:315) in the console. I've tried changing how I'm defining and the order in which I'm loading my app and angular, but I still get the same error.

I have found similar questions on here, but nothing has solved my problem. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my require js files as well as my angular app definition:

(main.js)

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: '../js/angular/angular.min',
        jquery: '../js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min',
        app: '../js/app',
        nvd3: '../js/nvd3/nv.d3.min',
        d3: '../js/d3/d3.min',      
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },        
        nvd3: {
            exports: 'nv',
            deps: ['d3']
        },
        d3: { exports: 'd3'},     
    }
});
```

(loadAngular.js)

```
require([
      'angular',
      'app',
      'services/services',
      'controllers/controllers',
      'directives/directives',
      'd3',
      'nvd3',

    ], function(angular) {
//        angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
    });
```

(app.js)

```
require(["angular"], function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    // create the angular app
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['MyApp.directives'
    ]);

    app.factory('socket', function () {
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:7000');
        return socket;

    });

    // setup dependency injection
    angular.module('d3', []);
    angular.module('MyApp.directives', ['d3']);

    angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);

});
```

UPDATE:
I think I've discovered where the error is being thrown from. I have the main.js file in a script tag in my base.html file, I am then loading the actual content views (with the angular stuff in) into a div using a jquery .load() call. Each of the fragment html files have the loadAngular.js included.

The error is thrown from inside the dynamically loaded view (ng-app='MyApp'):

```
<div id='trans' ng-app='MyApp' ng-controller='TransController'>
```

This makes me think that I'm not using RequireJS to properly load angular onto the page? Can anyone see any mistakes in the files?

Comment: Where is main.js included in your page? At the end?  You can also try manually running angular.module('moduleName'); it will throw an except ion if the module isn't availble.

Comment: Did you follow the link?: "Module 'true' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

Comment: Main.js is included in a template layout html file, the pages with the content are loaded using the jQuery .load() function into a div within that base.html file. I have loadAngular.js included in the loaded content files